# Can I make Unity Autoscale according to monitor size, resolution and dot pitch?

Tags: unity, resolution

I have noticed that unity does a pretty good job at moving from resolution to resolution with the folded icons in the dock but I've just used an application that resizes the dock fr my laptop to 32px. It's not a huge difference in size but what a difference in room!

Obviously I wouldn't want this on my 24" screen, so is there a way?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something that Unity currently doesn't do itself in 11.04.

(Though someone might be able to make a script that changes the CCSM value based on your resolution and then change value, so it's not totally impossible).